Practical applications of dandelin spheres
I know that dandelin spheres can be used to prove the focal properties of conic sections, but I heard that they can be used to help track the orbits of planets. All the sources I looked up only said that orbits were conic sections and did not provide details on how dandelin spheres would be used to work with orbits. Does anyone know if they are used to work with orbits, and if so, how they are used to work with them?

I have never come across an actual application of this construction, nothing beyond what is in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandelin_spheres
